# File operation in C giving bizzare output

Tags: c, file-io

I'm running a piece of C code that takes information from 10 [Dynamixel](http://support.robotis.com/en/software/dynamixel_sdk/api_reference.htm) servo motors ( ID, position, angle , load-torque ) and prints them to the screen as well as writes it to a log file ( watchdog_log.txt).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dynamixel.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <dynamixelAX.h>
#include "utils_v2.h"
#include "low_level_v2AX.h"
#include "low_level_v2.h"


// Control table address
#define P_GOAL_POSITION_L       30
#define P_GOAL_POSITION_H       31
#define P_PRESENT_POSITION_L    36
#define P_PRESENT_POSITION_H    37
#define P_MOVING                46


// Defulat setting
#define DEFAULT_BAUDNUM         34 // 1Mbps
#define DEFAULT_BAUDNUM_AX  1
#define DEFAULT_ID              1


int main()
{
  FILE *fp;

  /* Get actuator ID from command line argument */
  int baudnum = 34;
  int baudnum_AX = 1;
  int deviceIndex = 0;
  int deviceIndex_AX = 1;
  int current;
  float load, angle;

  int i=0;
  int MOTOR_CHAIN[13]={-1,1,1,0,0,0,-1,1,1,0,0,0,-1};
  int MOTOR_CHAIN_AX[18]={2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}; 
  int MOTOR_HOME[13]={404,444,3216,2037,2289,512,860,661,879,3474,1747,512};  //0, 6 and 12 are dummy
  int MOTOR_HOME_AX[18]={512,512,512,512,512,512,512,512,512,512,512,512,512,512,512,512,512,512,};

  char report[1000];
  char buffer[50];


  strcpy(report,"***********\n");

  /* Initialise Open USB2Dynamixel */
  if( dxl_initialize(deviceIndex, baudnum) == 0 )
    {
      printf( "Failed to open USB2Dynamixel!-chain'0'\n" );
      printf( "Press Enter key to terminate...\n" );

    }
  else
    printf( "Successfully opened USB2Dynamixel 0!\n" );

 if( dxl_initializeAX(deviceIndex_AX, baudnum_AX) == 0 )
    {
      printf( "Failed to open USB2Dynamixel!-chain'1'\n" );
      printf( "Press Enter key to terminate...\n" );
    }
  else
    printf( "Successfully opened USB2Dynamixel 1!\n" );


  /*  Ping all devices */
  printf("Pinging devices...");

  for( i=0; i<=12; i++)
  {
    dxl_ping(i);

   if (dxl_get_result() == COMM_RXSUCCESS)
   { 
    current = (fabs(dxl_read_word(i, 0x34)-512)*10);
    load = dxl_read_word(i, 0x28);
    if (load>=1024)
    load=(load-1024)*0.1;
    else load=load*0.1;

    int theta = dxl_read_word(i, 36);
    angle = counttoangle(MOTOR_CHAIN[i], MOTOR_HOME[i], theta);
    printf("ID: %d success,      Load:  %3.1f,       Count =  %d,     Angle =   %3.2f\n", i, load, theta, angle) ;
    sprintf(buffer,"ID: %d success,      Load:  %3.1f,       Count =  %d,     Angle =   %3.2f\n",i, load, theta, angle);
    strcat(report,buffer);

   }
  else printf("ID: %d failure\n",i);
 }


//File operations
strcat(report,"***********\n\n\n");

fp = fopen("watchdog_log.txt","w"); /* append file (add text to a file or create a file if it does not exist.*/ 
fprintf(fp,"%s",report); /*writes to file*/
fclose(fp); /*done!*/** 

 /* Close device */
  dxl_terminateAX();
  return 0;
  }
```

I am running the code every one second using 'watch' command on Ubuntu to constantly monitor the output of the code on the screen.

```
watch -n 1 ./watchdog
```

The output on the terminal is normal when file operations are not done. But when file writing is done, the terminal gives bizzare outputs:

**Normal Output**
[image: Normal Output]

**Bizzare Output**
[image: Bizzare Output]

Any help on the above problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the content at least the right one?

Comment: Yeah, contents of the log file are correct.

Comment: That bizarre output looks like a core dump.  Maybe your process is segfaulting?

Comment: note that you aren't checking the `fp` returned by `fopen`

Comment: Run it under a debugger. I suspect either your `fopen` is returning NULL (check for that and print `errno` if so - maybe full disk or wrong permissions?), or `dxl_terminateAX` is segfaulting somehow.

Comment: Can you please tell me how it looks like when you open it with a text-editor?

Comment: I noticed you have a `**` after the comments where you call `fclose();`. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it (I suspect not). Typo in copy/paste? I think that'd cause compile errors, anyway.

Comment: I concur with debugger use, though. My thought, not being familiar with your API and the devices, that somehow using C file IO along with the dxl API calls may be causing side-effects (perhaps with colliding file descriptors).

Comment: Your buffer is only 50 chars long, but each line in the report is longer than that.  Also, why create a long in-memory string instead of writing to the log file as necessary?  Finally, if all you need is to send the output to the terminal and a file you might be able to just pipe your output to the `tee` program.

Comment: The output you're seeing is the contents of a `/proc/<pid>/maps` pseudo-file.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance probles is in your variables:
`char report[1000];`
`char buffer[50];`

they are overflowed whe you are working with them.
for example
`sprintf(buffer,"ID: %d success,      Load:  %3.1f,       Count =  %d,     Angle =   %3.2f\n",i, load, theta, angle);`
The minimum size of the string is greater than 50 bytes!
So you can try increase the size of your string vars or calc needed size and allocate them in heap ...